# Why should I use the & sign on structs?

Tags: go

In the gotour, there is a section: struct literals.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

var (
   v1 = Vertex{1, 2}  // has type Vertex
   v2 = Vertex{X: 1}  // Y:0 is implicit
   v3 = Vertex{}      // X:0 and Y:0
   p  = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex
)

func main() {
   fmt.Println(v1, p, v2, v3)
}
```

What's the difference between a struct with an ampersand and the one without? I know that the ones with ampersands point to the same reference,  but why should I use them over the regular ones?

```
 var p = &Vertex{} // why should I use this
 var c = Vertex{} // over this
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments pretty much spell it out:

```
   v1 = Vertex{1, 2}  // has type Vertex
   p  = &Vertex{1, 2} // has type *Vertex
```

As in many other languages, `&` [takes the address](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) of the identifier following it. This is useful when you want a pointer rather than a value.

If you need to understand more about pointers in programming, you could start with [this](http://goinbigdata.com/golang-pass-by-pointer-vs-pass-by-value/) for go, or even the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) page.

Answer (score 48):

It's true that `p` (`&Vertex{}`) has type `*Vertex` and that `c` (`Vertex{}`) has type `Vertex`.

However, I don't believe that statement really answers the question of *why* one would choose one over the other. It'd be kind of like answering the question "why use planes over cars" with something like "planes are winged, cars aren't." (Obviously we all know what wings are, but you get the point).

But it also wouldn't be very helpful to simply say "go learn about pointers" (though I think it is a *really* good idea to so nonetheless).

---

How you choose basically boils down to the following.

- Realize that `&Vertex{}` and `Vertex{}` are fundamentally initialized in the same way.

  - There might be some low-level memory allocation differences (i.e. stack vs heap), but you really should just let the compiler worry about these details
- What makes one more useful and performant than the other is determined by how they are *used* in the program.
- "Do I want a pointer to the struct (`p`), or just the struct (`c`)?"

  - Note that you can get a pointer using the `&` operator (e.g. `&c`); you can dereference a pointer to get the value using `*` (e.g. `*p`)

    - So depending on what you choose, you may end up doing a lot of `*p` or `&c`
    - Bottom-line: create what you will use; if you don't need a pointer, don't make one (this will help more with "optimizations" in the long run).

---

- Should I use `Vertex{}` or `&Vertex{}`?

  - For the `Vertex` given in your example, I'd choose `Vertex{}` to a get a simple value object.
  - Some reasons:

    - `Vertex` in the example is pretty small in terms of size. Copying is cheap.
    - Garbage collection is simplified, garbage creation may be mitigated by the compiler
    - Pointers can get tricky and add unnecessary cognitive load to the programmer (i.e. gets harder to maintain)
    - Pointers aren't something you want if you ever get into concurrency (i.e. it's unsafe)
    - `Vertex` doesn't really contain anything worth mutating (just return/create a new `Vertex` when needed).
  - Some reasons why you'd want `&Struct{}`

    - If `Struct` has a member caching some state that needs to be changed inside the original object itself.
    - `Struct` is *huge*, and you've done enough profiling to determine that the cost of copying is significant.

      - As an aside: you should try to keep your `struct`s small, it's just good practice.
    - You find yourself making copies by accident (this is a bit of a stretch):

      ```
       v := Struct{}
      v2 := v  // Copy happens
      ```

      ```
       v := &Struct{}
      v2 := v  // Only a pointer is copied
      ```

Comment: This is a thorough answer to the original question, it provided the foundational knowledge about copy of values vs. copy of pointers to the readers, which unlocked the puzzle many had about & in front of a struct type name. Well done!

Comment: Any article which demonstrates real-life use cases would be great

Comment: I've seen an example in a Go course: `type Capper struct {output io.Writer}` (also `Capper` implements `Write` method) and then `c := &Capper{os.Stdout}`. Is there a reason to use a pointer here?