# why return &strut than return a ${name, 0}

Tags: go

code:

```
type account struct {
    owner   string
    balance int
}
func NewAccount(owner string) *account {
    account := account{owner: owner, balance: 0}
    return &account
}
```

question:
**Why NewAccount return value is &{name, 0} why not a memory address ?**

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48135731/1524867 and see if that doesn't answer this for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why should I use the & sign on structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135694/why-should-i-use-the-sign-on-structs)

Comment: By the way, after creating a local variable named `account`, you will not be able to access the type `account`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default `fmt` print format. See the section on **verbs** to understand how the change the format: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing

```golang
fmt.Println(NewAccount("name"))
// output: &{name 0}
```

```golang
fmt.Printf("%p\n", NewAccount("name"))
// output: 0xc00010c040
```

https://play.golang.org/p/I-EC_1yTqT-

---

Alternatively use the builtin [`print`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#print) or [`println`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#println) functions, but keep in mind that these are not guaranteed to stay in the language.

```golang
println(NewAccount("name"))
// output: 0xc0000a0f60
```

https://play.golang.org/p/bH97NGStYsi